# How can I check a string is exist and add require?

Tags: solidity

I have function to add a category and a message. I want to see if a category has already been added in this function. After detecting this, I want to set a special message sending fee for that category.

Question 1: How can I check for a previously inserted string?

Question 2: How do I write a different price condition for a pre-attached string than for a non-pre-added string?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <=0.9.0;

contract MFC {
    address payable owner;
    uint public minPrice = 1 ether;
    uint public _minPrice = minPrice + 1 ether;
    uint public cur_Price;
    uint public category_Price;
    string public categoryName;
    uint public p = 1 ether;
    constructor () {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }    

    event AddMessage        (address recipient, uint messageId);
    event DeleteMessage     (uint tweetId, bool isDeleted);

    struct Message {
        uint id;
        address username;
        string categoryName;
        string messageText;
        bool isDeleted;
        uint curPrice;
        uint categoryPrice;
    } 

    Message[] public messages;

    mapping(uint256 => Message) messageToOwner;
    mapping(string => uint) cPr;
    

    function getCpr (string memory category) public view returns (uint) {
        return cPr[category];
    }

    function addMessage(string memory _categoryName, string memory _messageText, bool _isDeleted) external payable {
        
        cur_Price = msg.value;
        categoryName = _categoryName;
        uint messageId = messages.length;
        p = p + msg.value;
 


    // This is not working as I want.
    if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_categoryName)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked(cPr[categoryName]))) {
        require(msg.value >= minPrice );
            } else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_categoryName)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(cPr[categoryName]))){
                require(msg.value > p);
    }

    
     


     messages.push(
            Message({
                id : messageId, 
                username : msg.sender, 
                categoryName : _categoryName, 
                messageText : _messageText, 
                isDeleted : _isDeleted, 
                curPrice : cur_Price,
                categoryPrice : cur_Price
                })
        );


        cPr[_categoryName] = msg.value;
        emit AddMessage(msg.sender, messageId);

    }

    function getInfo(uint _messageId) public view returns (Message memory) {
        require(_messageId < messages.length);
        return messages[_messageId];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand what you intend to do with the second question, so could you provide more clarification on that? Would be easier for me to help you.

Regarding the first question, just do a bytes32 to bool mapping that would store every keccak hash of the string that you are checking. Just turn the bool for the corresponding string to true when you add it, and then use it to check if it exists. Something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7; 

contract example {
    mapping (bytes32=>bool) isTheStringAlreadyAdded; // use a mapping like this one to indicate if the string that you are checking has already been added.
    uint  public i; // for example purposes 


function addCategory(string memory _string) public {
    isTheStringAlreadyAdded[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_string))] = true;
}

    function checkCategory (string memory _string) public {
        require(isTheStringAlreadyAdded[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_string))] == false, "This category has already been added");
       i+=1;  /// the rest of your logic can be written here, the i variable is for example purposes
    }
}
```

or you can use the same code , but add a custom error and an if statement, because it is more gas efficient. Like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7; 

contract example1 {
    mapping (bytes32=>bool) isTheStringAlreadyAdded;
    uint  public i; //for example purposes
    error categoryisAlreadyAdded();


function addCategory(string memory _string) public {
    isTheStringAlreadyAdded[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_string))] = true;
}

    function checkCategory (string memory _string) public {
        if(isTheStringAlreadyAdded[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_string))] == true) {
         revert categoryisAlreadyAdded();
        }
        else {
        i+=1; // the rest of your logic is here
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Actually, that's my goal. I want to send a message to category A by paying a fee. The person who wants to send a new message to the same category must pay more than the first person to send the message.

Example:
If it's the first post in the category, charge the minimum fee.
If it's not the first message, pay a higher price than the previous message.

Comment: Then I guess you could use the code in the answer as a foundation and build on top of it. Happy that I helped you and good luck!